# Plot Dataset, convert to time series

Tags: plotting, dataset, date-and-time, time-series

How do I plot an imported dataset? In `pandas` one can use `pd.DataFrame.plot()`, which includes multiple column plotting too.

How do I convert a specific column of a dataset into a `TimeSeries`? In `pandas` it can be done by `squeeze` or `pd.Series`.

Example dataset:

```
t = DateRange[DateObject@{2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
   DateObject@{2000, 1, 2, 0, 0} , "Hour"];
dt = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {Length[t], 2}];
col = {"values1", "values2"};
Dataset@AssociationThread[t, AssociationThread[col, #] & /@ dt]
```

Comment: `TimeSeries[Normal[ds]]` will convert the whole dataset into a TimeSeries object when the data structure is DateObjects as keys, which you have in this case. To convert just one column, you could do `TimeSeries[Normal@ds[All, "values1"]]`. If the question is about _plotting_ this dataset, you could do `DateListPlot[Transpose[ds]]`.